# Nested while loop to calculate distance for multiple destinations

Tags: perl, geolocation, while-loop

Oke I'm messing up pretty bad now. I wanted to create a proper script using stricts and warnings (still a challenge for me;).  But now I'm completely lost. I've been looking at so many examples that I'm totally confused. What I'm trying is to calculate the distance between 2 points using lat/lon. I think I have that part covered with gis::distance. BUT the problem is I'm trying to find destinations that are within 5000m of each other. (and skip if the destinations are the same). So when it finds a destination that's within 5000m of another destination I want it to place it after the last element in the first file.

Both input files are the same, here's how they look. Both files have about 45k lines.

```
Europe;3;France;23;Parijs;42545;48,856555;2,350976
Europe;3;France;23;Parisot;84459;44,264381;1,857827
Europe;3;France;23;Parlan;11337;44,828976;2,172435
Europe;3;France;23;Parnac;35670;46,4533;1,4425
Europe;3;France;23;Parnans;22065;45,1097;5,1456
```

Let's say that 2 of these destinations are near each other, I'm trying to output it like so:

```
Europe;3;France;23;Parijs;42545;48,856555;2,350976;Parlan;11337;200
Europe;3;France;23;Parisot;84459;44,264381;1,857827;
Europe;3;France;23;Parlan;11337;44,828976;2,172435;
Europe;3;France;23;Parnac;35670;46,4533;1,4425;Parisot;84459;2000;Parnans;22065;350
Europe;3;France;23;Parnans;22065;45,1097;5,1456;
```

The actual result will match more  than 2 of course. In the outputfile the matched destination, destination id and calculated distance are added. It's possible that there are multiple matches for each destination. Pff this is really hard to explain haha. As i said I'm using strict&warnings and narrowed the errors down to a minimum but still not completely. These are the errors:

```
Global symbol "$infile1" requires explicit package name at E:\etc.pl line 17.
Execution of E:\etc.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

This is the code I have so far. I'm not making heads or tails with the my declarations as well.

Can someone help me? (maybe this isn't the most effective way but for now it helps me understand perl more, step by step)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use GIS::Distance::Lite qw(distance);

my $inputfile1 = shift || die "Give input!\n";
my $inputfile2 = shift || die "Give more input!\n";
my $outputfile = shift || die "Give output!\n";

open my $INFILE1, '<', $inputfile1  or die "In use/Not found :$!\n";
open my $INFILE2, '<', $inputfile2  or die "In use/Not found :$!\n";
open my $OUTFILE, '>', $outputfile  or die "In use/Not found :$!\n";

my $maxdist = 5000;
my $mindist = 0.0001;

while ( my @infile1 ){ 
    my @elements = split(";",$infile1);

    my $lat1 = $elements[6];
    my $lon1 = $elements[7];

    $lat1 =~ s/,/./g;
    $lon1 =~ s/,/./g;

    seek my $infile2, 0, 0;

    print "1. $lat1\n";
    print "2. $lon1\n";

    while ( my @infile2 ){
        my @loopelements = split(";",$infile2);

        my $lat2 = $loopelements[6];
        my $lon2 = $loopelements[7];

        $lat2 =~ s/,/./g;
        $lon2 =~ s/,/./g;

        print "3. $lat1\n";
        print "4. $lon1\n";

        my $distance = distance($lat1, $lon1 => $lat2, $lon2);      # Afstand berekenen tussen latlon1 and latlon2

        print "5. $distance\n";

        my $afstand = sprintf("%.4f",$distance);

        print "6. $afstand\n";

        if (($afstand < $maxdist) and (!($elements[4] == $loopelements[4]))){ 
            push (@elements, $afstand,$loopelements[4],$loopelements[5]);
            print "7. $afstand\n";
            } else {
                next;
                }
        }

  @elements = join(";",@elements);  # add ';' to all elements
  print OUTFILE "@elements";
  #if ($i == 10) {last;}
  }
close(INFILE1);
close(INFILE2);
close(OUTFILE);
```

--------------- EDIT --------------

Well, here i am again. I've been looking at your updated code and this is a pretty intense version of mine haha. I honestly have to say i only understand half of it. It's still pretty helpfull; al of it! I decided to stick to my original script design with your improvements but it's still not working. I have a few questions about that if you don't mind:

I made af few adjustments in the script. The first one is that it now skips latlons with a zero because that would give a useless result. In the same line it also skips empty cells which is also useless. I have done this for both the infiles.

Oh and where i said elements[4] i ment elements[5], so it would be numbers. So i switched the ne for a != if i'm not mistaken. But i think i created an infinite loop again because it's not looping through the second file. I know i may seem stubborn but i wanted to first understand my original script and start working on your version as soon as i got mine running. The seek function isn't working properly i think. Here is the script as it is now.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use GIS::Distance::Lite qw(distance);

my $inputfile1 = shift || die "Give input!\n";
my $inputfile2 = shift || die "Give more input!\n";
my $outputfile = shift || die "Give output!\n";

open my $INFILE1, '<', $inputfile1  or die "In use/Not found :$!\n";
open my $INFILE2, '<', $inputfile2  or die "In use/Not found :$!\n";
open my $OUTFILE, '>', $outputfile  or die "In use/Not found :$!\n";

my $maxdist = 3000;
my $mindist = 0.0001;

while (my $infile1 = <$INFILE1> ){
  chomp $infile1;
  my @elements = split(";",$infile1);

  print "1. $elements[6]\n";
  print "2. $elements[7]\n";

  my $lat1 = $elements[6];
  my $lon1 = $elements[7];

if ((($lat1 and $lon1) ne '0') and (!($lat1 and $lon1) eq "")){
        $lat1 =~ s/,/./;
        $lon1 =~ s/,/./;
        print "lat1: $lat1\n";
        print "lon1: $lon1\n";  
        } else {
            next;
            }

  print "3. $lat1\n";
  print "4. $lon1\n";

  seek $INFILE2, 0, 0;

  while ( my $infile2 = <$INFILE2> ){
    chomp $infile2;
    my @loopelements = split(";",$infile2);

print "5. $elements[6]\n";
print "6. $elements[7]\n";

    my $lat2 = $loopelements[6];
    my $lon2 = $loopelements[7];

if ((($lat2 and $lon2) ne '0') and (!($lat2 and $lon2) eq "")){
        $lat2 =~ s/,/./;
        $lon2 =~ s/,/./;
        print "lat2: $lat1\n";
        print "lon2: $lon1\n";  
        } else {
            next;
            }

my $distance = distance($lat1, $lon1 => $lat2, $lon2);      # Afstand berekenen tussen latlon1 and latlon2

print "7. $distance\n";

my $afstand = sprintf("%.4f",$distance);

print "8. $afstand\n";

if ($afstand < $maxdist && $elements[4] != $loopelements[4]){ 
  push (@elements, $afstand, $loopelements[4],$loopelements[5]);
  print "9. $afstand\n";
    } else {
        next;
        }
  }
print $OUTFILE join(";",@elements), "\n";
}

close($INFILE1);
close($INFILE2);
close($OUTFILE);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got it pretty good already. Let's take a look at your error messages.

> Global symbol "$infile1" requires explicit package name at E:\etc.pl line 17.

This one is simple. In Perl, all [variable names](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#The-Syntax-of-Variable-Names) are    case-sensitive.    At the top, you create a [lexical](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) variable    `$INFILE1`. I'll talk more    about lexical in a minute.

```
open my $INFILE1, '<', $inputfile1  or die "In use/Not found :$!\n";
```

Here you've got it in all-caps, which is ok. You may do that if it    helps you to remember that it's a lexical file handle (file    handles    used to be global and named like `INFILE1`). **But** later on (in line 17) you use `$infile1`.

```
my @elements = split(";",$infile1);
```

You have not declared that variable (with `my`), so it throws this    error. But that is not all.

I believe you are trying to read from that file handle. But that does not work. I'll explain this in steps.
 - In fact, you've built an infinite loop, but you are not yet aware of it.

```
    while ( my @infile1 ){
```

This `while` loop will not stop. Ever. The declaration of `@infile1` with `my` always returns a true value, because it always    works. So you'll never break the loop.

- I guess you're trying to read the file line by line. So let's see how we can do that:

  ```
  while (my $infile1 = <$INFILE1> ){ 
    my @elements = split(";",$infile1);
  ```

  You need to read from the file like this. Now the assignment in the `while` loop's head will be true only as long as there is a line    returned from the file handle. Once it is at the end of the file, it    will return `undef`, thus ending the loop. Yay. Also note how your    `$infile1` in the next line with `split` now is correct.

  You also need to add [`chomp`](http://p3rl.org/chomp) to the mix, because there are new line characters at the end of the file:

  ```
  while (my $infile1 = <$INFILE1> ){ 
    chomp $infile1;
    my @elements = split(";",$infile1);
  ```
- Next is the `seek` line. This looks like you want to read the second file from the beginning for each line of the first file. That    makes sense in a way, but is very inefficient. I'll talk about that    later. You do need to change the `my` though. You don't have to create a new variable here. Also, use the correct name:

  ```
  seek $INFILE2, 0, 0;
  ```
- Let's instead fix the second `while` loop:

  ```
  while (my $infile2 = <$INFILE2>){
    chomp $infile2;
    my @loopelements = split(";",$infile2);
  ```
- The next thing I noticed was in line 42:

  ```
  my $distance = distance($lat1, $lon1 => $lat2, $lon2);
  ```

  Don't worry, there is nothing wrong here. I'd just like to note that    the `=>` is another way to write a comma (`,`). It's called the *fat comma* sometimes and it makes it easier to read, for example, hash  assignments.
- In line 50 you've already got the distance.

  ```
  if (($afstand < $maxdist) and (!($elements[4] == $loopelements[4]))){
  ```

  [`and`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-And) is usually used to do error checking. See the perldoc as to why. You should use [`&&`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-And) instead. Because it has higher    precedence, you can leave out the parenthesis. You can also change your `!($a == $b)` construct to use the [`!=`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) operator instead. **But** since it holds the city name, and that is a string and not a number, you need to use `ne`, which is the opposite of `eq`. So this line now becomes:

  ```
  if ($afstand < $maxdist && $elements[4] ne $loopelements[4]){
  ```

  It's a lot better to read, isn't it?
- In line 58 you `join` your array `@elements` and assign it to itself. That is rather strange. It will replace the array with a new    array that has only one element - the joined string. Let's leave that    line until the next bullet and look at it then.
- In line 59 you've got a `print` statement, but you are now using a global file handle `OUTFILE` that you have never created. Instead,    you need to use your lexical file handle from the top, `$OUTFILE`. If    we now add the `join` from the line above directly to the print    statement and also add a `\n` new line character at the end, the line    becomes:

  ```
  print $OUTFILE join(";",@elements), "\n";
  ```
- Now only the last part remains: You need to close the file handles, but again you're using global ones. Use your lexical ones    instead:

  ```
  close($INFILE1);
  close($INFILE2);
  close($OUTFILE);
  ```

The complete code now looks like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use GIS::Distance::Lite qw(distance);

my $inputfile1 = shift || die "Give input!\n";
my $inputfile2 = shift || die "Give more input!\n";
my $outputfile = shift || die "Give output!\n";

open my $INFILE1, '<', $inputfile1  or die "In use/Not found :$!\n";
open my $INFILE2, '<', $inputfile2  or die "In use/Not found :$!\n";
open my $OUTFILE, '>', $outputfile  or die "In use/Not found :$!\n";

my $maxdist = 5000;
my $mindist = 0.0001;

while (my $infile1 = <$INFILE1> ){
  chomp $infile1;
  my @elements = split(";",$infile1);

  my $lat1 = $elements[6];
  my $lon1 = $elements[7];

  $lat1 =~ s/,/./g;
  $lon1 =~ s/,/./g;

  print "1. $lat1\n";
  print "2. $lon1\n";

  seek $INFILE2, 0, 0;

  while ( my $infile2 = <$INFILE2> ){
    chomp $infile2;
    my @loopelements = split(";",$infile2);

    my $lat2 = $loopelements[6];
    my $lon2 = $loopelements[7];

    $lat2 =~ s/,/./g;
    $lon2 =~ s/,/./g;

    print "3. $lat1\n";
    print "4. $lon1\n";

    my $distance = distance($lat1, $lon1 => $lat2, $lon2);      # Afstand berekenen tussen latlon1 and latlon2

    print "5. $distance\n";

    my $afstand = sprintf("%.4f",$distance);

    print "6. $afstand\n";

    if ($afstand < $maxdist && $elements[4] ne $loopelements[4]){ 
      push (@elements, $afstand,$loopelements[4],$loopelements[5]);
      print "7. $afstand\n";
    } else {
      next;
    }
  }

  print $OUTFILE join(";",@elements), "\n";
}

close($INFILE1);
close($INFILE2);
close($OUTFILE);
```

---

Now to the way your algorithm works: It would be a lot more efficient to first read the complete second file and then do the comparison with the first file in each iteration. That way, you only have to read the file once.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use GIS::Distance::Lite qw(distance);
use feature qw(say);

my $inputfile1 = shift || die "first file missing";
my $inputfile2 = shift || die "second file missing";
my $outputfile = shift || die "output file missing!";

# Read the second file first
my @file2; # save the lines of INFILE2 as array refs
open my $INFILE2, '<', $inputfile2  or die "In use/Not found :$!";
while ( my $infile2 = <$INFILE2> ){ 
  chomp $infile2;
  my @loopelements = split(/;/, $infile2);

  $loopelements[6] =~ y/,/./;
  $loopelements[7] =~ y/,/./;

  push @file2, \@loopelements;
}
close($INFILE2);

open my $INFILE1, '<', $inputfile1  or die "In use/Not found :$!";
open my $OUTFILE, '>', $outputfile  or die "In use/Not found :$!";

my $maxdist = 5000;
my $mindist = 0.0001;

while (my $infile1 = <$INFILE1> ){
  chomp $infile1;
  my @elements = split(";",$infile1);

  my $lat1 = $elements[6];
  my $lon1 = $elements[7];

  $lat1 =~ y/,/./;
  $lon1 =~ y/,/./;

  say "1. $lat1";
  say "2. $lon1";

  FILE2: foreach my $loopelements ( @file2 ){
    my ($lat2, $lon2) = @$loopelements[6, 7];

    say "3. $lat2";
    say "4. $lon2";

    my $distance = distance($lat1, $lon1 => $lat2, $lon2);      # Afstand berekenen tussen latlon1 and latlon2

    say "5. $distance";

    my $afstand = sprintf("%.4f",$distance);

    say "6. $afstand";

    if ($afstand < $maxdist && $elements[4] ne $$loopelements[4]){ 
      push (@elements, $afstand, $$loopelements[4], $$loopelements[5]);
      say "7. $afstand";
    } else {
      next FILE2;
    }
  }

  say $OUTFILE join(";",@elements);
}

close($INFILE1);
close($OUTFILE);
```

Now, let's look at what I changed.

- First of all, I added `use feature qw(say)` to the top. [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) is the same as `print`, but a new line is added. That saves some typing. Also see [`feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#The-%27say%27-feature) for more info.
- I removed the "\n" characters from all `die` statements. If you put a new line there, it removes the line number from the output. If that was intended, ignore this suggestion please. Here's what [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) has to say to this:

  > If the last element of LIST does not end in a newline, the current
  >   script line number and input line number (if any) are also printed,
  >   and a newline is supplied.
- The most important part is the change to the algorithm I made. I moved the `while` loop for the second file outside of the other `while` loop, to the top of the program. The file is slurped into the array `@file2`. Each element holds an array ref with the fields of the line. The commas are already changed to full stop signs.

  I changed the [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) substitution operator to a [`y///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/y.html) (short of [`tr///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html)) transliteration operator. Since you only change one sign, this is sufficient. It is also faster. Even if you'd leave the regex substitution in, you would not need the `/g` modifier, because a float only ever has one comma, so it does not have to do multiple substitutions.

  Now all these things are done only once for file2. This saves considerable computing time when done 40k+ times.
- I changed the wording of the error messages so they can be understood better. That is preference. You don't have to do that.
- I changed the second `while` to a `foreach` loop to iterate over the elements of the new `@file2` array. I did leave the `$lat2` and `$lon2` vars in for clarity. You could omit these, and directly work with the array(ref) elements. In the assignment I used an [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) to put it into one line.
- Since `$loopelements` replaces `@loopelements` and it is an array ref, we need to access the data stored within using `$$loopelements[$index]` now.

I hope this helps you understand why I have made certain improvements.

Please remember that in Perl There Is More Than One Way To Do It - that is a good thing. 
There seldom is *the right way*, but often many ways that lead to the goal. Some are more efficient than others, while these others sometimes are easier to maintain. The trick is to find the right balance between these two cases.

---

**Update:**

Here are the input files I have used. You will need them to compare results.

*file1.csv*:

```
Europe;3;France;23;Parijs;42545;48,856555;2,350976
Europe;3;France;23;Parisot;84459;44,264381;1,857827
Europe;3;France;23;Parlan;11337;44,828976;2,172435
Europe;3;France;23;Parnac;35670;46,4533;1,4425
Europe;3;France;23;Parnans;22065;45,1097;5,1456
```

*file2.csv*:

```
Europe;3;France;23;Parlan;11337;44,828976;2,172435
Europe;3;France;23;Parnac;35670;46,4533;1,4425
Europe;3;France;23;Parnans;22065;45,1097;5,1456
Europe;3;France;23;Parijs;42545;48,856555;2,350976
Europe;3;France;23;Parisot;84459;44,264381;1,857827
```

Comment: I'm going to add suggestions to this.

Comment: I think `$elements[4]` is the city name, so he needs to use `ne` not `!=`.

Comment: I'm still fixing glitches. I'll come to that in a minute. Thanks @cjm

Comment: I'll add the other things later.

Comment: @simbabque Wow, thanks for the explanation! This helps a lot. This i can really work with.. I especially appreciate the explanation of why it's not working! Sorry i don't have a more elaborate thank you haha. I'll get on it right away!

Comment: @Nick: you are welcome. I added a few more suggestions as well as an improved algorithm to the answer.

Comment: @simbabque Made several adjustments in my code based on your suggestions but it's still not working. I made an edit in my first post where i added my findings. Do you have suggestions on how to fix this?:)

Comment: @Nick: When I run your updated code it says `Argument "Parijs" isn't numeric in numeric ne (!=)`. It seems you forgot to replace the index `4` with `5` in your `if ($afstand < $maxdist && $elements[4] != $loopelements[4]){` line. It should read `if ($afstand < $maxdist && $elements[5] != $loopelements[5]){`. Once I did this, I got a result:`Europe;3;France;23;Parijs;42545;48,856555;2,350976
Europe;3;France;23;Parisot;84459;44,264381;1,857827
Europe;3;France;23;Parlan;11337;44,828976;2,172435
Europe;3;France;23;Parnac;35670;46,4533;1,4425
Europe;3;France;23;Parnans;22065;45,1097;5,1456`

Comment: @simbabque Hi i think i got most of it and its working now:) There were a few other mistakes aswel, while debugging i printed out the results but i was printing out the wrong elements so i got confused haha. I do have 2 last questions if its oke? When i print out the end result ($afstand) it displays it correct (12808.6827) as in 12km. But when it gets printed to the file and i open it, it says 128.086.827? The other question is i get the following warning "Use of uninitialized value $lat2 in string ne at". I checked it and those strings are empty, can i ignore this? Check is built in

Comment: @nick: Update the code and the lines of the input that produce the strange output. If it says "Use of uninitialized value in string `ne`" you probably have a blank line at the end of your file that you need to take care of. Add something like `next if $infile1 eq '';` after the `chomp $infile` line. That should take care of the warning. (In general, you should never ignore a warning, they are there for a reason ;-))

Comment: @simbabque I found out what was causing the dots on the output.. Stupid excel was inserting dots every 1000 for readability. The output in vim was correct. Aah i see, i thought i had a solution but i guess that wasn't enough. Working on it. Have i mentioned thank you before?;)

Comment: **Don't use Excel** to check CSV files. It will always mess something up. ;)

Comment: @simbabque So true! Thats what i'm learing the hard way haha. There's always something going wrong with excel. Didn't have another option atm:p Now on the whole reading second file first etc. The input files are actually identical so i could use just 1 file for both loops. I am trying to use only 1 filehandle and "simply" loop over the same file twice but i can't tell the seek to look for the INFILE1 because loop 1 is using is as well right?

Comment: Just read it once, store it in a data structure like I did in my edit, and loop over that data structure in the outer and the inner loop. Do not try to mess with the file handle. Storing it in memory is much more efficient. You don't want `seek` here, anyway. It is used to reread a certain length of bytes.

Comment: @simbabque It finally works:) Thanks for al your help and patience;) I started out with my original script like i said so i could understand it (sort of) and then started on your version. Most of it makes sense except the array referencing. I find it difficult getting a grasp on it. Think i have to study it a bit more. Also the "FILE2" in front of the foreach and after the "next" in the if. Is it just for clarification or actual code? Never seen something like it before. 
**edit** I forgot, is there a way to output only the lines where results get pushed at the end?

Comment: @nick:The `FILE2: foreach` is called a [*label*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements). I like to use it if I have nested loops. It's for clarification, but also for control. With it, you can `next FILE1` or `last OUTER` while you are inside the inner loop. You can also label a block and do something like `LABEL { ...code ... more code last LABEL if $a; .. more code }`. Look at the number of elements in `@elements`, like `say join ';' @elem if @elem > 8`. The array in string context gives you the number of elements in it.